# how to change the default value of Bootstrap select

Tags: bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm using the Bootstrap-Select plugin like this:

```
<select class="selectpicker dropup"></select>
<button>Add option</button>
```

and jQuery code:

```
$(function(){

  $(".selectpicker").selectpicker('hide');

  $(button).click(function() {
     $(".selectpicker").append(`
      <option value="">--Choose option--</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
     `);
     $(".selectpicker").selectpicker('refresh');
     $(".selectpicker").selectpicker('show');
  });

});
```

But when select appears, it does not take the first option as default but has text like image. Can I change this depending on the select?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Bootstrap select for multiple choice (https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) and I had to change the default behaviour, it's not the same as yours but I hope it can give an hint anyway.

In our case we had to **update the default style**. The default style is a bootstrap `btn-default`, and I was able to update it with the following code:

```js
$('#my-select').selectpicker({
styleBase: 'form-control',
style: '',
});
```

More [here](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/options/#default-settings)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the text 'Nothing Selected', set the title property to whatever you need.

eg : **title="My Custom Text"**

```
<select class="selectpicker dropup" title="My Custom Text"></select>
<button>Add option</button>
```